# Can't get into SE chat on Safari iOS 8.1 or 8.1.1

Tags: bug, chat, login, mobile-safari

[image: screenshot]Although I can load chat in Chrome on my iPad, I cannot in Safari (which I prefer to use because of MathJax, which runs fine on Safari). I'm getting some sort of HTML5 error when I run the diagnostics. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: I'll work on that. Oh, and since OS8.1, I still haven't been able to download the latest iOS-app, either. I've tried dozens of times. :(

Comment: Are you able to log in to stackexchange.com?

Comment: Yes, although it doesn't keep me logged in the way it used to (for weeks on end).

Comment: To have a user see your comment, you need to use `@`, e.g. @Anna see Ted's response above.